# how to calculate sum of a series? (me or Wangenmakers is wrong)

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning

Wagenmakers in his critical [article](http://www.ejwagenmakers.com/2007/pValueProblems.pdf) about p-values wrote that:

$$\sum_{i=12}^{\infty} {{n-1} \choose {2}}  \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \approx .033$$

How could he do his calculations if the  D'Alembert's criterion shows that the series diverges?

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{ {n \choose 2} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} } {{{n-1} \choose {2}}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^n}= 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{n!(n-2)!}{2!}}{\frac{(n-1)!\cdot(n-3)!}{2!}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\cdot (n-2)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\infty >1$

If I'm wrong, how can I evaluate the series above explicitly (to reach this 0.033)?

Comment: Your computation of ${n\choose 2}$ is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed.  $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $\binom{n-1}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$, leading you for the center line to be $\lim \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{n}{n-2}<1$ so it converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact... First,
$$
\sum_{n=12}^\infty \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\;x^n = \frac{x^{12}(45x^2-99x+55)}{(1-x)^3}
$$
obtained by differentiating the geometric series $\sum_{n=12}^\infty x^{n-1}$ twice.
So
$$
\sum_{n=12}^\infty \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\;\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = 
\frac{67}{2048} \approx 0.0327
$$

Comment: Ok, I understand this solution, but what if $\sum (n-1)(n-2)..(n-5)(\frac{1}{2})^n$. Should I differentiate 5 times?

Comment: That generalization is left to the reader.

Comment: So I kindly ask for a short, emboldening hint ("yes"/ "no").

Comment: @Lili: Yes. $\,$

Comment: @Lili, why not just try it and see what happens?!

Comment: @Lili, if you are not too keen on doing the differentiation you could use the method of multiplication by $x$

by reindexing write the function $f(x)$ like this (I omit the summation signs)

$f(x)= c_nx^n= c_{n+1}x^{n+1}= c_{n+2}x^{n+2}$

it is possible to find constants $a,b,c$ such that

$a f(x) + b f(x)/x + c f(x)\left/x^2\right.=$ a constant times a geometric series + a few terms

this would give you $f(x)$

the $a,b,c$ would come from the observation that 

$\left\{c_n,c_{n+1},c_{n+2},1\right\}$ are linearly dependent, so

$a c_n+ b c_{n+1}+c c_{n+2}=$ a constant

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I tried anyway yesterday, but I always fear that I will get stuck (I think it's a common problem with maths) I will also tried Lozenges's advice today.